# Google Sheets First Query Taking Very Long

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I have a very small Google sheet I am using as a database for a project. Querying just 1 cell takes an average 20 seconds to complete. After the first query, any subsequent queries are only seconds behind. Any explanation for this slow start up?

Code (link to sheet and api key redacted):

```
    static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "autovhl";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "my api key here",
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        string spreadsheetId = "my sheet id here";
        string range = "Sheet1!A1:A2";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

        ValueRange response = request.Execute();
        IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());

    }
```

outputs:

4/28/2018 2:02:31 PM

done

4/28/2018 2:02:53 PM

Taking 22 seconds to query 2 cells.

Edit:
After waiting a few hours, the problem seems to have gone away. Maybe if a lot of requests are being made Google  throttles the  connection

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @Artemious updated.

Comment: First time when it executes, it opens a web-browser on a Google account login page. Does this explain your delay? I tested your code - it runs within 0.5 sec on my machine, except for the first time, when I had to sign in.

Comment: Evidently, it's not the case.

Comment: Have you tried to first create the SheetsService and then reuse it for other requests? Does the instantiation of it takes most of the time? You can use Diagnostic tools in Visual Studio to see what exactly takes so long in the method.

Comment: Also it well may be that your connection to the concrete Google API endpoint is poor and slow.

Comment: And try another spreadsheet. Perhaps, there's some problem with the one you use. It may be too large or too complex.